# Vertex Buffer Objects (Delete process) opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

When should i call glDeleteBuffersARB ? Should I do it when application ends? Can I somehow automatize the process of deletion vertex buffer object? For instance something like smart_ptr does.

Comment: Delete it when it's not used anymore.

Comment: hm, so can I create class for vbo with destructor which will delete vbo object? And then create objects as smart_ptr to automatize everything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never. You should never call `glDeleteBuffersARB`. Buffer objects have been core GL functionality for upwards of a decade now; if you're still using the ARB-suffixed extensions functions, *STOP*. If you're follow a tutorial that uses them, again *STOP*; it's clearly too old to be useful.

Now, when should you use [`glDeleteBuffers`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDeleteBuffers)? You should use it at the same time you would `delete` for a regular C++ object. That is, use it when you are *finished* with the object. When you have no more use for it and want to get rid of it.

> so can I create class for vbo with destructor which will delete vbo object? And then create objects as smart_ptr to automatize everything?

You could, but it's not going to buy you all that much. Also, you run the *very real* risk of waiting to delete the object until it's too late.

It is illegal to call any OpenGL function before the OpenGL context is created (and made current) or whenever a GL context is not current (for example, after you've destroyed the GL context). Attempts to do so are not good.

If you use `shared_ptr` to manage these resources, it becomes theoretically possible for them to outlive the actual OpenGL context. That's bad. Personally, I would prefer a more rigid management scheme, one that firmly ties the lifetime of the GL objects to that of the context.

Comment: Well, you could encapsulate the context in a class instance of its own and pass shared_ptr or weak_ptr as initialization parameter to any OpenGL object class. Actually I think to properly wrap OpenGL into C++ classes, OpenGL object class instances should only be returned by factory functions of the context class.

Comment: I still think that `shared_ptr` is good for OpenGL resource management. It still can be used to manage them 'indirectly' - so that deleting the resource wrapper class would not call glDelete* but mark this resource as 'freed' so they can be glDeleted some time later when appropriate(e.g. when respectful context becomes current). And this doesn't prevent context-manager class to delete(glDelete) those resources before context is destroyed even if they're not marked as 'free' by the mentioned wrapper class.