# Does glDeleteVertexArrays lead to deletion of VBOs, associated with VAO being deleted?

Tags: opengl, vbo

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573684/vertex-buffer-objects-delete-process-opengl) question, glDeleteBuffers marks buffer's video memory as free. But when I call glDeleteVertexArrays on a VAO, will this call delete all VBOs, linked with this VAO?

If no, when should I delete VBOs? Before deleting the VAO or after that?

Comment: Please don't call them "VBO"s. Buffer objects can [do a *lot* more](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use) than store vertex data.

Comment: While this is true, VBO is a very common and understandable among beginners.  Not to mention the terminology of vertex does not seem to mean *position* any in OpenGL land.

Comment: For those looking for a succinct answer, you delete the VAO before the VBO. There are endless "ifs", "ands", and "buts" to this, but if each VAO has its own private VBO (as is common when learning), this is best practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But when I call glDeleteVertexArrays on a VAO, will this call delete all VBOs, linked with this VAO?

No. It will simply no longer reference them. And if you have deleted those buffer objects, and no other objects reference them, (FYI: VAOs are not the only things that can reference buffer objects), and they are not bound to any context, *then* their storage will be destroyed.